# Why running laravel app under jwilder/nginx-proxy I got 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error?

Tags: docker, nginx, jwilder-nginx-proxy

Running laravel project based on jwilder/nginx-proxy I got error in browser

```
503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
nginx/1.21.1
```

with url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:80
```

Running docker and checking containers in my OS I see :

```
$ docker-compose up -d
nginx-projectname is up-to-date
php-radius is up-to-date
mysql-projectname is up-to-date
php-userend is up-to-date
php-projectname is up-to-date
user@HostingOS:/ProjectPath/lml$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                          PORTS                               NAMES
b4ccbc8fdeda   roneichiarandi/php71-alpine   "/entrypoint.sh php-…"   3 hours ago    Up 21 minutes                   0.0.0.0:32770->9000/tcp             php-projectname
0b16d2c805df   mysql:latest                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago    Up 20 minutes                   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql-projectname
8b9f111aa298   roneichiarandi/php71-alpine   "/entrypoint.sh php-…"   3 hours ago    Up 21 minutes                   0.0.0.0:32768->9000/tcp             php-radius
3ae492cfdd89   roneichiarandi/php71-alpine   "/entrypoint.sh php-…"   3 hours ago    Up 21 minutes                   0.0.0.0:32769->9000/tcp             php-userend
2db8d9b0901e   jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest    "/app/docker-entrypo…"   3 hours ago    Up 20 minutes                   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                  nginx-projectname
9b9bf003a1a3   jwilder/nginx-proxy           "/app/docker-entrypo…"   7 hours ago    Exited (2) 6 hours ago                                              inspiring_lovelace
05626a8da615   jwilder/nginx-proxy           "/app/docker-entrypo…"   7 hours ago    Created                                                             adoring_goldwasser
e5dddc493fe2   adminer                       "entrypoint.sh docke…"   8 months ago   Up 2 hours                      0.0.0.0:8095->8080/tcp              gotoconsult_adminer
0c6a52f43a8b   mysql:5.7.28                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 months ago   Restarting (1) 44 seconds ago                                       gotoconsult_db
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx: # NGINX-PROXY
    image: 'jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest'
    container_name: 'nginx-projectname'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
      - ./docker/nginx.tmpl:/app/nginx.tmpl
      - .:/var/www/html

  # PHP7-alpine fpm
  php:
    container_name: 'php-projectname'
    image: 'roneichiarandi/php71-alpine'
    ports:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./logs:/tmp/logs
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=projectname.dev
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=
      - PHP_FPM=1
    links:
      - 'radius'
    extra_hosts:
      - "radius.dev:172.18.0.1"

  # PHP7-alpine fpm
  userend:
    container_name: 'php-userend'
    # image: 'matriphe/alpine-php:fpm-5.6'
    image: 'roneichiarandi/php71-alpine'
    ports:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ../userend:/var/www/html
      - ../userend/logs:/tmp/logs
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=userend.dev
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=
      - PHP_FPM=1

  # PHP7-alpine fpm
  radius:
    container_name: 'php-radius'
    image: 'roneichiarandi/php71-alpine'
    ports:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ../radius:/var/www/html
      - ../radius/logs:/tmp/logs
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=radius.dev
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=
      - PHP_FPM=1

  mysql:
    container_name: 'mysql-projectname'
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - mysqlvolume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=projectname

volumes:
    mysqlvolume:
```

I suppose url is valid

```
http://127.0.0.1:80
```

but what have I check in nginx options?

**MODIFIED :**
Checking nginx logs I see :

```
user@HostingOS:/ProjectPath$ docker-compose logs nginx
Attaching to projectname
projectname | WARNING: /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem was not found. A pre-generated dhparam.pem will be used for now while a new one
projectname | is being generated in the background.  Once the new dhparam.pem is in place, nginx will be reloaded.
projectname | forego      | starting dockergen.1 on port 5000
projectname | forego      | starting nginx.1 on port 5100
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: using the "epoll" event method
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: nginx/1.21.1
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: built by gcc 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: OS: Linux 4.15.0-128-generic
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: start worker processes
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 34
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 35
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 36
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:56 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 37
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 Generated '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' from 7 containers
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 Running 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: signal 1 (SIGHUP) received from 40, reconfiguring
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: reconfiguring
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 Watching docker events
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: using the "epoll" event method
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: start worker processes
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 44
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 45
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 46
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 47
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 34#34: gracefully shutting down
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 35#35: gracefully shutting down
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 36#36: gracefully shutting down
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 34#34: exiting
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 35#35: exiting
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 36#36: exiting
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 34#34: exit
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 35#35: exit
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 36#36: exit
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 37#37: gracefully shutting down
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 37#37: exiting
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 37#37: exit
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 34
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: worker process 34 exited with code 0
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: worker process 35 exited with code 0
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: worker process 36 exited with code 0
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 37
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: worker process 37 exited with code 0
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:31:57 [notice] 27#27: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:32:00 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:32:00 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 49#49: signal process started
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: signal 1 (SIGHUP) received from 49, reconfiguring
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: reconfiguring
projectname | Generating DSA parameters, 4096 bit long prime
projectname | dhparam generation complete, reloading nginx
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: using the "epoll" event method
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: start worker processes
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 51
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 52
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 53
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: start worker process 54
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 44#44: gracefully shutting down
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 45#45: gracefully shutting down
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 46#46: gracefully shutting down
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 47#47: gracefully shutting down
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 44#44: exiting
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 45#45: exiting
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 47#47: exiting
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 46#46: exiting
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 44#44: exit
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 45#45: exit
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 47#47: exit
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 46#46: exit
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 47
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: worker process 47 exited with code 0
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 46
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: worker process 44 exited with code 0
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: worker process 46 exited with code 0
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 45
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: worker process 45 exited with code 0
projectname | nginx.1     | 2021/09/01 10:32:02 [notice] 27#27: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:32:03 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:32:03 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:32:29 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:32:29 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:32:32 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:32:32 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | nginx.1     | 213.109.234.130 83.4.217.73 - - [01/Sep/2021:10:33:21 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/601.7.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.2 Safari/601.7.7"
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:33:24 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:33:24 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:33:26 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:33:27 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:34:27 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:34:27 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:34:29 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:34:30 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:35:30 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:35:31 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:35:33 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:35:33 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:36:34 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:36:34 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:36:36 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:36:36 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:37:37 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:37:37 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:37:39 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:37:40 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | nginx.1     | 213.109.234.130 205.185.126.200 - - [01/Sep/2021:10:37:54 +0300] "POST /boaform/admin/formLogin HTTP/1.1" 503 197 "http://213.109.234.130:80/admin/login.asp" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0"
projectname | nginx.1     | _ 205.185.126.200 - - [01/Sep/2021:10:37:56 +0300] "" 400 0 "-" "-"
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:38:40 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:38:40 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:38:42 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:38:43 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:39:43 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:39:43 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:39:46 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:39:46 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:40:47 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:40:47 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:40:49 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:40:49 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:41:50 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:41:50 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:41:52 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:41:53 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:42:53 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:42:53 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:42:56 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:42:56 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:43:57 Received event start for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:43:57 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:43:59 Received event die for container 0c6a52f43a8b
projectname | dockergen.1 | 2021/09/01 10:43:59 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'
projectname | SIGQUIT: quit
```

Any hints how it can be checked/fixed ?

Entering the bas with command :

```
docker-compose exec nginx bash
```

I check root directory and find file dhparam.pem.default:

```
root@2db8d9b0901e:/app# ls -la
total 112
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Aug 30 03:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4096 Sep  1 10:31 ..
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    54 Aug 30 03:01 .dockerignore
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root  4096 Aug 30 03:01 .github
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    34 Aug 30 03:01 .gitignore
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root  2244 Aug 30 03:01 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root  2223 Aug 30 03:01 Dockerfile.alpine
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root  1079 Aug 30 03:01 LICENSE
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root   472 Aug 30 03:01 Makefile
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root   115 Aug 30 03:01 Procfile
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root 29137 Aug 30 03:01 README.md
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root   424 Aug 30 03:01 dhparam.pem.default
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root   534 Aug 30 03:01 docker-compose-separate-containers.yml
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root   281 Aug 30 03:01 docker-compose.yml
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  1448 Aug 30 03:01 docker-entrypoint.sh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root  2058 Aug 30 03:01 generate-dhparam.sh
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root   133 Aug 30 03:01 network_internal.conf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 10096 Aug 31 18:26 nginx.tmpl
drwxrwxrwx 14 root root  4096 Aug 30 03:01 test
root@2db8d9b0901e:/app# cat dhparam.pem.default
-----BEGIN DH PARAMETERS-----
MIIBCAKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXBAg==
-----END DH PARAMETERS-----
```

but not requested dhparam.pem file ?

I run the docker with command :

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Can it be that I have to run docker command with some parameters dealing dhparam.pem file?
Like copying into into app root ?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls , look at MODIFIED